# Set reCaptcha field as required

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, recaptcha

I use the new reCaptcha with [the jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org) plugin. The validation plugin works nice with my form but unfortunately it didn't work with reCaptcha. My attempt to make it work below:

HTML:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" name="recaptcha" id="recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXX"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
 recaptcha: {
    required: true
      }
```

but it didn't worked. Does anyone know how to fix this. I simply need the default **This field is required** error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to make it worked. The only problem is after user completing reCaptcha, the message **This field is required** does not quickly dissapear.  I'm using blur, keydown and focusout to detect user input and remove the error message.

JS:

```
$("#myForm").bind('blur keydown focusout', function(){ 

        var dataArray = $("#myForm").serializeArray(),
        dataObj = {};
        console.dir(dataArray); //require firebug
        //console.log(dataArray);

        $(dataArray).each(function(i, field){
          dataObj[field.name] = field.value;
        });

        var recaptcha = (dataObj['g-recaptcha-response']);

        if(recaptcha != "") {
                $( "#temp" ).remove();
        }       
    });

    $( ".register" ).click(function() {

        var dataArray = $("#myForm").serializeArray(),
            dataObj = {};
            console.dir(dataArray); //require firebug
            //console.log(dataArray);

        $(dataArray).each(function(i, field){
          dataObj[field.name] = field.value;
        });

        var recaptcha = (dataObj['g-recaptcha-response']);

        $( "#temp" ).remove();

            if(recaptcha == "") {
                $("#recaptcha").append('<label id="temp" style="color:red;line-height:normal;font-size: small;">This field is required.</label>');
            }

    });             

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" name="recaptcha" id="recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should add hidden input for reCaptcha, cause jQuery Validation can only validate input/textarea/select:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXX"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha" data-rule-recaptcha="true">
<!-- 
     We set "data-rule-recaptcha" — this will require jQuery Validate
     to validate this field using method named "recaptcha"
     (which we write below) 
-->
```

Then rewrite your JS like this:

```
// By default jQuery Validation ignore hidden inputs, 
// so we change settings to ignore inputs with class "no-validation". 
// Cause our hidden input didn't have this class — it would be validated!
$('form').validate({
  ignore: '.no-validation'
});     

// Add our validation method for reCaptcha: 
$.validator.addMethod("recaptcha", function(value, element) {
  var grecaptcha = window.grecaptcha || null;
  return !grecaptcha || grecaptcha.getResponse();
}, "Please fill reCAPTCHA");
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" name="recaptcha" id="recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXX"></div>
```

with...

```
recaptcha: {
    required: true
}
```

You cannot validate a `<div>`.  Period.

The jQuery Validate plugin can ***only*** validate `<input>`, `<textarea>` and `<select>` elements that are also within a `<form></form>` container.

The only workaround would be to copy your value into a `type="hidden"` `input` element and then apply your validation to that.

Comment: @etoxin, be specific please.  My answer is statement of fact along with the only possible way to get around this limitation.  "Does not work" makes no sense in this context.

Answer (score -5):

hoping that you are using HTML5 form tag.

```
<form>
<div class="g-recaptcha" name="recaptcha" id="recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXX" required></div>
</form>
```

simply use **required** in the end

Comment: You cannot validate a `div`!  Only `input`, `textarea`, and `select` elements can be validated.