# How can I make reCaptcha required in this form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, recaptcha

How can I make this required?
HTML form code:

```
<div id="myDIV" style="">
<form name="login">
<h2 style="position:relative;right:107;bottom:10">Sign in</h2><p style="position:relative;right:55;bottom:5">to NASP Stacks database</p>
<input class="input" name="id" type="text" placeholder="Username"><br><br>
<input name="pass" type="password" class="input" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
<script>
{
  "success": true|false,
  "challenge_ts": timestamp,  // timestamp of the challenge load (ISO format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ)
  "hostname": string,         // the hostname of the site where the reCAPTCHA was solved
  "error-codes": [...]        // optional
}
</script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdHRDgUAAAAAFg8efAOvTVM_9crHq_UQm_aveaW"></div><br>
<b><input class="button" type="button" value="NEXT" onClick="pasuser(this.form)"></b>
</form>
</div>
```

How can I make the reCaptcha a required field in this form? I have tried other posts but they aren't working. I have added lots of things before but they didn't work and they clogged up the code. Anybody know how to make it required?

Answer (score 0):

just add `required` to your input:

```
<input class="button" type="button" value="NEXT" onClick="pasuser(this.form)" required>
```

note: I cannot understand your script code :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this related post? [reCaptcha field as required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657127/recaptcha-field-as-required)

I believe you will need to have a Javascript callback function to validate the response of the recaptcha before proceeding. Since your form doesn't have a submit input, I guess you will need to do the validation within the callback function of the onClick event.

```
onClick="pasuser(this.form)"
```